How to enforce user to accept terms to be able to pay with apple pay or google pay in woocommerce
How to enforce user to accept terms to be able to pay with apple pay or google pay in woocommerce ,i'm using stripe payment for woocomerce
i tried this snippet but it's not work
add_filter('wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', 'enforce_terms_for_express_checkout', 10, 3);

function enforce_terms_for_express_checkout($post_data, $order, $prepared_source) {
    if ( ! isset($_POST['terms']) || empty($_POST['terms']) ) {
        wc_add_notice('You must accept the terms and conditions before proceeding.', 'error');
        return false; // Prevent payment processing
    }
    return $post_data;
}


Please ensure Terms and Condition page is set in WooCommerce. WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Page Setup
